# React/Firebase : Implement Stripe Payment for Subscription

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am very much new to Stripe integration with Firebase.

I have the following which creates the payment_method in Stripe (can see in logs)

I want the user to subscribe to just one product that I have already set up in Stripe.

I tried paymentIntents.create etc but it returns an undefined error on create.

Can anyone please help?

```
const CheckoutForm = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (elements == null) {
      return;
    }

    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      billing_details: {
        email: 'test@test.com',
      },
    });



    if (error) {
      alert('1')
    } else {
      alert('2')
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardElement options={CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS} />
      <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe || !elements}>
        Pay
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

const stripePromise = loadStripe('XXX');

const CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS = {
  style: {
    base: {
      'color': '#32325d',
      'fontFamily': 'inherit',
      'fontSmoothing': 'antialiased',
      'fontSize': '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4',
      },
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a',
    },
  },
};

const SignUp = () => {
  

  return (
    <>
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <CheckoutForm />
  </Elements>
  </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just frontend code and you will need to create PaymentIntent on the backend. Reference [Stripe official Doc for CardElements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/card-element).

Additionally, you would want to [use PaymentElements instead](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements). PaymentElements is newer and supports various payment methods which will be beneficial in the long run.

Comment: thank you. Doesn’t Firebase give you the backend to create an endpoint though?

Comment: Yes it should. But what is the error you had when creating PaymentIntent?